# typing bin/jruby -S rails myapp I get the output telling me how to use the rails command?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby

I insalled jruby, and when I type:

```
> bin/jruby -S rails myapp 

I get:


bin/jruby -S rails myapp -d mysql
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]           # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                              # Default: /Users/snad/dev/jruby/jruby-1.5.2/bin/jruby
  -d, [--database=DATABASE]   # Preconfigure for selected database (options: mysql/oracle/postgresql/sqlite3/frontbase/ibm_db)
..
..
..
```

It seems to be conflicing with my rails (3.0) installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type `jruby -S rails --version`. I bet you have Rails 3.0.0 installed as jruby gem. So you should either use `jruby -S rails new myapp` to create an app or rollback to rails 2.3.8 if you need it for some specific reason.